# Removing data from an array when unchecking the checkbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

For this task, I'm trying to add storyId to a favorites array when a post's checkbox is clicked. Like so:
[image: Checked Box]
[image: Console result]

So I've got that part working. However, when I uncheck the checkbox, the same storyId is pushed to the array:
[image: Console after unchecking]

I've tried to create this using if/else statements:

```
async saveFavStory(storyId) {
console.log(storyId);

if (this.checked = "true") {
  this.favorites.push(storyId);
  console.log(this);
} else { 
  this.favorites.pop(storyId);
  console.log(this)
};
};
```

If someone could explain how to write this so that the storyId is removed from the favorites array when the checkbox is unchecked it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone will have different ways to accomplish this. I prefer to not use if statements to look through and remove unchecked items.

My solution is simple, on change regenerate the list based on what's checked.

```js
let stories = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
let favorites = [];

function createFavorites() {
  favorites = [];
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']:checked");
  checked.forEach(function(el) {
    favorites.push(el.value);
  });
  console.log(favorites)
}

stories.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function() {
    createFavorites();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> 1 Favorite
<input type="checkbox" value="2"> 2 Favorite
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> 3 Favorite
```

Answer (score 1):

When you uncheck, you need to use `filter` method to `filter` the `favorites` array from that specific item.

```js
if (this.checked == true) {
  this.favorites.push(storyId);
} else { 
  this.favorites = this.favorites.filter(id => id !== storyId);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send an attribute in the event which will tell you whether the checkbox is checked or not like this

```
const customEventCheck = new CustomEvent('childevent', {
detail:{val:event.target.value,checked:event.target.checked}
});
```

---

And in the parent, based on that value, you can add or remove the element.

```
var rowId = event.detail.val;
var checked=event.detail.checked;

if(checked){
this.checkedId.push(rowId);
}else{
    var index = this.checkedId.indexOf(rowId);
this.checkedId.splice(index, 1);
}
```